# restore original value after setprecision?

Tags: c++

I have search the web but couldn't find what I need.

Some people recommend using

```
streamsize ss = std::cout.precision();
```

but I couldn't get it to work.

How do I set a double value back to the original state after setprecision?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
 double a;
 cout << "enter a double value: ";
 cin >> a;
 cout << "your value in 3 decimals is " << setprecision(3) << fixed << a << endl;
 cout << "your original value is " << a << endl;

 return 0;
 }
```

Obviously the code above will not return the original value of a.

My intended output is: if user enter 1.267432

```
your value in 3 decimals is 1.267
your original value is 1.267432
```

Answer (score 2):

> How do I set a double value back to the original state after
> `setprecision`?

To do so, you have to get the precision before you use `setprecision()`. In your question you already mentioned it by the following line:

```
streamsize ss = std::cout.precision();
```

> but I couldn't get it to work.

Here how you use it:

```
streamsize ss = std::cout.precision();

double a = 1.267432;

std::cout << "a = " << a << '\n';

std::cout.precision (3);
std::cout << "a becomes = " << a << '\n';

std::cout.precision (ss);
std::cout << "Original a= " << a << '\n';
```

And the output will be like:

> a = 1.26743
>
> a becomes = 1.27
>
> Original a= 1.26743

Reference: [setprecision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision).

[Run live.](http://ideone.com/QWk5uJ)

Comment: This method does not work.  For example, if user enter 1.42324, the outputs are 0.000 and 1.423

Comment: @Tasmin, I edited the answer. Also I tested the code. It works exactly how you want. [Running code link](http://ideone.com/QWk5uJ).

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double a = 1.267432;
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::showpoint;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(3);
    std::cout << a << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: I tried this method multiple time before I posted the question, it just does not work.  Which I do not understand why.